# Custom Header Directory

Tags: miktex

On Windows Vista, I created a custom directory C:\MikTex\tex\latex\myheader for all my header files (mostly just .tex). Now I've installed Windows 7 and I can't seem to work out how I did it the last time. I'm using TexNicCenter for compiling and it always says that it can't find the files at all.

I think I had to do texhash whenever I changed something in the directory back then, but now doing texhash does nothing. Any help?

Comment: Did you re-do the "Define Output Profiles..." (Alt+F7) settings in TeXnicCenter?

Answer (score 2):

informations for integrating Local Additions can be found here:
http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html

Edit: Just did a little bit research and found some information about easily adding folders under windows [here](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html#id574074). I don't have a win PC here, so I can't test, but it should work

For me adding the path to the `TEXINPUTS` enviroment Variable is working perfectly. To add `TEXINPUTS` Variable press `windows` + `pause`, `advanced system settings`, `advanced` and then `enviroment variables`.

There you can choose between `user` and `system` based enviroment variables. `user` based only apply for your current user. Just click `new` to add `TEXINPUTS`.